# Adding row of one data frame at a specific spot in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble, rbind

I have a large data frame of 5520 by 5520. After every 120 rows I need to add another row. The values of these new rows are contained within dataframes of one row by 5520.

Using rbind I add these rows at the end of the table which I do not want. And gives me an error:
`fabioN2 <-rbind(fabioN2, auf2[1,]) Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :  names do not match previous names`

Using tibble with add_row I also get an error:
`> fabioN2 %>% add_row(fabioN2, auf2[1,], .after = 120) Error: New rows can't add columns. x Can't find columns` fabioN2`,` X1`,` X2`,` X3`,` X4`, and 5516 more in` .data`.`

With fabioN2 being the large dataframe and auf2 containing the values I want to add to fabioN2.
Undoubtedly the codes are wrong and based on the errors, I have to match the names of the columns of both the dataframes, something I want to prevent considering the 5520 different columns names.

Anyone know how to easily add these dataframes at the desired spots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got the logic right for your problem ... I did it for a data.frame of 30 rows to add a row every 10 rows (as 120 is to much for a reproducable example in terms of fitting the output in the answer).

```
library(dplyr)

r <- 3 # your number is 46 (5520/120)
l <- 10 # your number is 120

# your long data.frame where you want to fit in ever l rows
df1 <- data.frame(dx = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a",
                         "c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c", 
                         "e","e","e","e","e","e","e","e","e","e"))

# your data.frame of one row to fit in every l rows
df2 <- data.frame(dy = c("X"))

# set colnames to be identical
names(df2) <- colnames(df1) 

# use row number as ID and set it of as needed with the help of integer division
dff1 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = ID + (ID-1) %/% l)

# repeat your one row df according to the quantity needed and use the row number with set off calculation
dff2 <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::slice(rep(row_number(), r)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = (ID) * l + ID)

# union both data.frames (I am supposing column types are identical!)
dff1 %>% 
  dplyr::union(dff2) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(ID)

   dx ID
1   a  1
2   a  2
3   a  3
4   a  4
5   a  5
6   a  6
7   a  7
8   a  8
9   a  9
10  a 10
11  X 11
12  c 12
13  c 13
14  c 14
15  c 15
16  c 16
17  c 17
18  c 18
19  c 19
20  c 20
21  c 21
22  X 22
23  e 23
24  e 24
25  e 25
26  e 26
27  e 27
28  e 28
29  e 29
30  e 30
31  e 31
32  e 32
33  X 33
```